apt-get install python3.10 doesn't?
My WSL2-based Ubuntu is running python 3.8.10.  I'd like to update it to 3.10.x, so I typed:
sudo apt-get install python3.10

That produced a lot of output and appeared to complete without error, but at the end, I still got:
$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.10

...even after quitting the WSL2 shell and starting another.  Did I miss a step?

It doesn't install it as the default python3 (by redirecting the /usr/bin/python3 symlink) and that's a Very Good Thing since doing so would likely break stuff (including apt). You should still be able to run it as python3.10 though - you can always create an alias for use in your interactive shell.

... see related How to replace python3.10 with python3.12 in ubuntu 22.04 (answer: dont!).
